# C what is this line of code doing? Is it casting?

Tags: c, variables, casting

So I'm following an online tutorial (on OS development if that matters) and I saw this line of c code void. Here's a simplified version:

```
void function1(struct regs *r) {
  void (*handler)(struct regs *r);   // What happened here?

  // do things with void *handler
}
```

What happened in that line? It declared a variable

> void *handler

but it did something like a cast? but it doesnt seem like a cast. What just happened there?

Comment: [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*handler%29%28struct+regs+*%29) is a useful site for decoding declarations.

Comment: Look up on "Function pointers"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void (*handler)(struct regs *r);` declares `handler` as a pointer to a function that expects an argument of type `struct regs *` and returns type `void`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void (*handler)(struct regs *r);
```

This special form is a declaration of a function pointer. There is no cast involved here.

`handler` is a pointer to a function that takes an argument of type `struct regs *` and returns nothing.

It can be used like this:

```
void foo(struct regs *r)
{
    /* a function that takes an argument of type
     * struct regs * and returns nothing
     */
}

void (*handler)(struct regs *r);

handler = foo;  // assign foo to handler object

handler(NULL);  // call the function, here with a null pointer
                // to simplify the example
```

Answer (score 0):

The line is declaring a variable named `handler`. It's equivalent to

```
T * handler;
```

if `T` is `void(struct regs *)`. (The line also effects the declaration of the type `struct regs`.)

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers do look a bit weird. In this case, no casting or assignment is going on - this is just a variable declaration.

```
void (*<variable name>)(<function params>);
```

In your example above, `<variable name>` is `handler` and `<function params>` is `struct regs *r`.